# mapping value array length=0

Tags: solidity

I have a problem.I used addData() correctly, but anyway when I getDataLength() it always returns 0, what am I missing?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    mapping(address => address[]) public datas;


function addData(address data) public {
    datas[msg.sender].push(data);
}

function getDataLength() view public returns (uint256){
    return datas[msg.sender].length;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is empty because your addData function has an address argument, but you are entering arbitrary input (I guess) that gets reverted (failed) and as a result length never changes.

Comment: Yeah, buddy, that's a good guess!
I have found the problem, the function decorated by view, msg.sender is empty address!
Forgive me for being a solidity neophyte